# Text value from Label in GridView form with Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, gridview, label, getelementbyid

How I can get the Text value from GridView via JavaScript?

I tried this but it doesn't display value from Text = "this is a label":

```
                var lblThis = document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>')
                var lblThisTag = lblThis.document.getElementByTag('txtValueResultMandays').innerHTML
                alert(lblThisTag);
```

Sample:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mandays">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="txtValueResultMandays" runat="server" Text="this is a label"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I tried this:   document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').getElementsByTagName('<%=txtValueResultMandays.ClientID %>')  - Doesn't work((

Answer (score 0):

```
var lblThis = document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>')

if(grid.rows.length>0){
    //loop starts from because first row is columnNames
    for (i = 1; i < grid.rows.length-1; i++) {

        var label= grid.rows[i].cells[index of the cell with label].elements[0];
        alert(label.InnerHTML);                 

    }
}
```

You should try something like this.

Comment: `var label= grid.rows[i].cells[index of the cell with label].elements[0];`  What I must write in `index of the cell with label`  ??

Comment: @EldarNecefov the index of the cell which have the label

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to directly access the label value using jquery as given below if it has an id.

```
 var value = $('#<%=txtValueResultMandays.ClientID%>').val();
```

or try accessing it directly in java script using getElementById method instead of going through the grid.

Comment: When I try usint it, it gives the error. The name 'txtValueResultMandays' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Check the source of your page and check the id of the textbox there. Replace txtValueResultMandays.ClientID with that id.